# Conflicts between multiple jQuery libraries

Tags: jquery

How do I handle having two separate jQuery libraries? I need both of them, but including both results in a conflict, and only one's functions will work.

Comment: Why are you including **2** jQuery libraries? Why not kill the one with the least compatability with your other plugins and fix the issues with the plugin that requires the one you killed? Some snippet of what plugins you're using would help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends. You can actually have both of them active in the page at the same time, but only one of them can have the `$` symbol, and only one of them can have the `jQuery` symbol. But technically, you *can* have more than one on a page:

```
<script src="jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
<script>var $j15 = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script>
    // Here, $ = jQuery = jQuery 1.7.1
    // $j15 = jQuery 1.5.2
</script>
```

Note that a well-authored jQuery plug-in will work even in that environment, e.g.:

```
<script src="jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
<script src="plugin-requiring-1.5.2.js"></script>
<script>var $j15 = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script>
    // Here, $ = jQuery = jQuery 1.7.1
    // $j15 = jQuery 1.5.2
    $j15("selector").pluginRequiring152(...);
</script>
```

...because a well-authored plug-in looks like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.pluginRequiring152 = ...;
})(jQuery);
```

...and so will use whatever is `jQuery` at the point you include it, without breaking if you later fire off `noConflict(true)`.

Is it a good idea? Almost certainly not. Best to resolve whatever the issues are that make you need more than one version of jQuery, and only include the latest you've tested with.